# Problems with backBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to make a backBarButton so that it performs its function like in normal apps. I made a segue from my button to the previous view controller and chose "push". It 
works  like a normal button, but not like a backBarButtonItem should work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should embed the whole view with a NavigationController; in Xcode in the Storyboard : Editor - embed in navigation controller and change all the segues to push from modal.

You don't need a back button because it will be created automatically , the only segues you create is from vc1 to vc2 and the NavigationController takes care of the back button.

Comment: When I use a push segue, my app crashes?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use the NavigationController and are just trying to mimic the back button behavior you want to use popViewControllerAnimated not push.